# Log.i("tag", "text"); giving error cannot resolve symbol 'i'

Tags: android

```
 Log.i("tag", "text");

 // bla bla bla
```

is not working

Comment: did you try to clean your project ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This question arises when he does not know basics of java. Such questions should not be asked.

Comment: using a public static void function you are able to achieve what you want.
because without activity you are not able to print log so either you have to put into the public static function or you have to define into activity

Answer (score 3):

You need to call that inside a method. e.g.:

```
public static void makeInfoTag(String msg) {
        Log.i("tag", msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put it inside oncreate  or any other on funtion. if an activity.

else

create a construtor and log.

```
public AppSingleton () {
    Log.i("","");
}
```

Comment: Wrong answer. The class is not an activity

Answer (score 0):

You should using `Log` function in method or constructor, because `Log` function cannot identify the tag and msg while you type.

```
public class Appsingleton {
    // put Log func on Constructor 
    public Appsingleton() {
        Log.i("tag", "my message");
    }

    // put LOg on method
    public static void showLog(String message){
        Log.i("tag", message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do these steps:-

1. clean your project. 
   you can do that by clicking ( Build >> Clean project ).
2. then rebuild your project.
   you can do that by clicking ( Build >> Rebuild project ).

finally
Make Sure to put your code

> Log.i("tag", "text");

within the onCreat() method.